# QT: translation using button

Tags: qt, translation

Hello friends,
             I am creating some labels and information box in qt designer. Also i have created a push button for translation purposes. QT has &tr for whichever text can be translated to other language. Is there any way to connect this to the push button, where a drop down menu will tell the language choices. Or is there a way to save the translations somewhere and then bring them at the click of the push button. Kindly let me know. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Qt translations are saved in `.ts` files (one file for each language). If you have several translation files, you can put them into resources or in the installation directory.

you can get language list just as you can get usual files list - using `QDir::entryInfoList`. Or you can hardcode translations list in the source code.

You can load translation file using `QCoreApplication::installTranslator` and remove it using `QCoreApplication::removeTranslator`.

See also:

- [Qt Linguist Manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-manual.html)
- [Hello tr() Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-hellotr.html)
- [Dynamic Translation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html#dynamic-translation)